# EasyAutoComplete plugin Search multiple data and show only single value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a ways to search multiple fields in the data?

For example, it would be great for a user search where you can match the person's name as well as their username as in this data set below:

```
[  
   {  
      username:"blastermaster",
      fullname:"John Smith",
      avatar:"/path/to/avatar.jpg"
   }
]
```

So for this data set, searching for either "blaster" or "John" would match John Smith.

Comment: use datatable, which provides options to search on multiple columns

Comment: @Rahul How is it possible to use datatable in autocomplete?